# Adding fade out effect to the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, list, fadeout, collectionview

I want to add a fade effect to the top of the collection view as in the photo below. The list in this photo is a feature that exists in the live broadcast of Instagram. I tried CAGradientLayer but didn't get the result I wanted. Thanks in advance for the help.

Instagram Live List: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUj77.jpg

Edit: I want this effect to always stay at the top of the list. Btw, things I've tried with CAGradientLayer:

```
private func setFadeOut() {
let collectionViewGradient = CAGradientLayer()
collectionViewGradient.colors = [
    UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor,
    UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.1).cgColor,
    UIColor.clear.cgColor
]
collectionViewGradient.frame = view.bounds
collectionViewGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
collectionViewGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
collectionView.layer.insertSublayer(collectionViewGradient, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: Is this an effect that animates the collection view away during a transition? Or are you saying that "vignette" effect is at the top of the collection view at all times? You say "I tried CAGradientLayer but didn't get the result I wanted." What, exactly, did you try (show your code.) And how did it fail to meet your needs? "It didn't work" is maddeningly uninformative.

Comment: (I'm tempted to reach for the close button. I'll wait, and give you a chance to edit your question, but others are likely to close it unless you provide a lot more info.)

Comment: @DuncanC I made the necessary corrections, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't configured the gradient properly. Your color order was incorrect and you are missing locations.

Try this:

```
    private func setFadeOut() {
    let collectionViewGradient = CAGradientLayer()
    collectionViewGradient.colors = [
        UIColor.gray.cgColor,
        UIColor.white.cgColor,
        UIColor.white.cgColor,
        UIColor.gray.cgColor
    ]
    collectionViewGradient.locations = [0, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0]
    collectionViewGradient.frame = view.bounds
    collectionView.layer.insertSublayer(collectionViewGradient, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this code sets the top of the list to black and the rest to white.

Comment: Create a UIView, fill it above the UICollectionView in the UIView hierarchy, than call setFadeOut() on that UIView

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a view class like the one below.
Place your gradient view wherever you want (top, bottom), set its frame and make sure the z-ordering is ok (bring it to front if needed).
The `distance` argument determines the transition region in points.

An example - if you place it at the top and set its frame height to be 150 and `distance` to be 100, the gradient will progress over 100 points and the remaining 50 points on top will be pure black (or whatever color you set it to).

Typically you want to place it so that it transitions over the safe area and the remaining unsafe area is pure black (under the notch etc).

The view instance needs to be created programmatically but this is what you seem to be doing anyway. It won't be difficult to modify it for Interface Builder use.

```
import UIKit

class EdgeGradientView: UIView {
    
    static override var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    
    enum Placement {
        case top
        case bottom
    }
    
    private let placement: Placement
    private let distance: Int
    private let color: UIColor
    
    init(placement: Placement, distance: Int, color: UIColor) {
        self.placement = placement
        self.distance = distance
        self.color = color
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        configureGradient()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        updateGradient()
    }

    private func configureGradient() {
        let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            color.cgColor,
            color.cgColor,
            color.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor
        ]
        switch placement {
        case .top:
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        case .bottom:
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        }
        
        updateGradient()

    }
    
    private func updateGradient() {
        let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0 - Double(distance) / Double(bounds.height), 1.0] as [NSNumber]
    }
}
```

Instantiate with:

```
let gradient = EdgeGradientView(placement: .top, distance: 100, color: .black)
```